# Summing The Contents Of A Three Tiered Array PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

This is the array I am using (3 tiers), and I am trying to add the number of sales (nosales) from the first month in the first array to the first month in the second array (Should be 150) and so on through all the variables (months shouldn't be added) so I am left with a two level array with the nosales, salevalue,salecost and saleprofit totals for each month.

```
Array    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [month] => 1
                        [nosales] => 100
                        [salevalue] => 1200
                        [salecost] => 360
                        [saleprofit] => 840
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [month] => 2
                        [nosales] => 110
                        [salevalue] => 1320
                        [salecost] => 396
                        [saleprofit] => 924
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [month] => 1
                        [nosales] => 50
                        [salevalue] => 350
                        [salecost] => 70
                        [saleprofit] => 280
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [month] => 2
                        [nosales] => 55
                        [salevalue] => 385
                        [salecost] => 77
                        [saleprofit] => 308
                    )

            )

    )
```

Now, I have tried looping through them to get them to add together but I am getting a number of errors. Could someone please help?

Here is the script I am using at the moment:

```
$acc = array_shift($results_array);

foreach ($results_array as $val) {
    foreach ($val as $v) {
        foreach ($v as $key => $v){
        $acc[$key] += $v;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Do you want to add only first month or you want to add all the first month with the first month, and second month with a second month? What is expected output?

Comment: I want values from month one to be compiled into month one, month two into month two so I am left with a single array that is a total of all of them. Seems someone has given me the correct answer already :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you wanted to do?

```
$aResultsArray = array(
    0 => array(
        1 => array(
            'month' => 1,
            'nosales' => 100,
            'salevalue' => 1200,
            'saleconst' => 360,
            'saleprofit' => 840,
        ),
        2 => array(
            'month' => 2,
            'nosales' => 110,
            'salevalue' => 1320,
            'saleconst' => 396,
            'saleprofit' => 924,
        ),
    ),
    1 => array(
        1 => array(
            'month' => 1,
            'nosales' => 50,
            'salevalue' => 350,
            'saleconst' => 70,
            'saleprofit' => 280,
        ),
        2 => array(
            'month' => 2,
            'nosales' => 55,
            'salevalue' => 385,
            'saleconst' => 77,
            'saleprofit' => 308,
        ),
    ),
);

$aSum = array();
foreach ($aResultsArray as $mYear => $aMonths) {
    foreach ($aMonths as $mMonth => $aMonth) {

        if (!isset($aSum[$aMonth['month']])) {
            $aSum[$aMonth['month']] = array(
                'month' => $aMonth['month'],
                'nosales' => 0,
                'salevalue' => 0,
                'saleconst' => 0,
                'saleprofit' => 0,

            );
        }

        $aSum[$aMonth['month']]['nosales'] += $aMonth['nosales'];
        $aSum[$aMonth['month']]['salevalue'] += $aMonth['salevalue'];
        $aSum[$aMonth['month']]['saleconst'] += $aMonth['saleconst'];
        $aSum[$aMonth['month']]['saleprofit'] += $aMonth['saleprofit'];

    }
}
var_dump($aSum);
```

Comment: Thanks, it did exactly what I wanted it to do.